# Airflow BigQuery Hook - Run update query via run_query

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to run some update queries after a bunch of tasks got over inside a DAG. So I'm going to create a python function for getting the necessary details from the previous task output and then by using [`run_query`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook/index.html#airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook.BigQueryBaseCursor.run_query) I want to update a table.

Here is my python function for this.

```py
def metatable_update(dag,tablename,schedule,**kwargs):
    bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',location='europe-west3',use_legacy_sql=False)
    pg_conn = config[schedule][tablename][1]
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    pgmax_ts = str(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_maxts_{}_{}'.format(tablename,pg_conn))[1])
    bq_hook.run_query(sql="update bqadmin.tablesync_meta set max_value='{}' where tablename='{}'".format(pgmax_ts,tablename))
```

My question is just simply use this code, or do I need to add something like `execute` or `return` for successfully run this task?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I have used BQ hook itself to solve this

And dont need to mention execute or return.

```py
def metatable_update(dag,tablename,schedule,**kwargs):
    bq_hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default',location='europe-west3',use_legacy_sql=False)
    pg_conn = config[schedule][tablename][1]
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    pgmax_ts = str(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_maxts_{}_{}'.format(tablename,pg_conn))[1])
    bq_hook.run(sql="update bqadmin.tablesync_meta set max_value='{}' where tablename='{}' and datasource_dbconn='{}'".format(pgmax_ts,tablename,pg_conn))
    return 'Executed the update query'
```